# Throw error on parameter check or let it hit the fan?

Tags: c, error-handling, error-checking

I'm writing a simple program that has a couple of functions that look like these:

```
float foo (float* m,size_t n){

   float result;
   //do some calculations, for example a sum 


   return result / n;
}
```

Should I add a sanity check on the `n`? If so, how should I let the caller know?

Returning `-1` looks weird on floats;

```
float foo(float *m,size_t n){
     if (n == 0) return -1f

     ...
  }
```

My other option is an out parameter

```
float foo(float *m,size_t n, int *error){

        if (n==0){
           *error = 1;
            return 0f;
        }
       ...
}
```

This is *kind of* a toy program, just trying to practice some stuff. The question exceeds that fact. Maybe I should rephrase to "how to handle errors without (OOP) exceptions".

I'm also considering testing `n` before doing the call, but don't like it as much.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It might be helpful to hear more about the functions' environment.  Do they exist in a body of code with established error-checking practices, or where third-party code has certain expectations?  Is this a standalone toy project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your `out parameter` option is a good one. But I guess it would be better the other way. Use the out parameter to get the result and the return value to denote the status of the call. Like this

```
int foo(float *m, size_t n, float* result)
{
  if(someFailureCondition)
    return ERROR; // ERROR being an error integer
  // else
  // do some calculation
  // set your result
  return NO_ERROR; // NO_ERROR being an integer
}
```

**Edit:**
The return value can be more verbose to denote the current state of the out parameter. See Jamesdlin's comment!

Comment: I prefer this style too for checking for runtime errors, but you additionally should explicitly state (as part of the function's contract) what the state of the output parameters are on failure (e.g. are they in an undefined state, left untouched, or set to some specific value).

Answer (score 2):

If -1 would not be returned by the function anyway, by all means return -1. But if passing n=0 won't break the function, then it isn't really needed. I assume that n is the size of the array m.

Handling errors is a matter of preference. OpenGL handles errors by returning an error code (-1 or otherwise) when a function fails. The error code is returned througha call to GetLastError() (or something like that). This seems like an ideal error handling solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are special floating point values you can use if you want - for example, if your floating-point implementation supports quiet NaNs (Not-a-Number) then you can use the `NAN` macro from `math.h`:

```
#include <math.h>
float foo(float *m,size_t n)
{
     if (n == 0) return NAN;

     ...
}
```

Comment: Considered it, but isn't it the "do nothing" case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It's supposed to be similar to your `-1f` case, except that you test for it with `isnan()`, and it will propagate through subsequent floating-point computations.

Answer (score 1):

You should let callers know what your function's semantics are by clearly documenting your code.

What is the contract to your function?  If callers are required to not pass 0 for `n`, then that needs to be explained, and the function should use `assert` to verify that those requirements are met.  *Logical errors* should be detected early, and those failures should be as spectacular as possible.

Now, if you're writing code for a library that will be consumed by other developers and are concerned that people will compile with `assert` disabled, then it's reasonable to combine that with a softer failure mode that's always enabled:

```
if (n == 0)
{
    assert(0);
    return NAN; /* Or return some error code */
}
```